# Amazon Neptune Full Text Search - specify fields

Tags: elasticsearch, gremlin, amazon-neptune

So [SPARQL documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/full-text-search-sparql-examples.html) contains examples how to specify multiple fields to search for:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX neptune-fts: <http://aws.amazon.com/neptune/vocab/v01/services/fts#>
SELECT * WHERE {
  SERVICE neptune-fts:search {
    neptune-fts:config neptune-fts:endpoint 'http://your-es-endpoint.com' .
    neptune-fts:config neptune-fts:queryType 'query_string' .
    neptune-fts:config neptune-fts:query 'mikael~ OR rondelli' .
    neptune-fts:config neptune-fts:field foaf:name .
    neptune-fts:config neptune-fts:field foaf:surname .
    neptune-fts:config neptune-fts:return ?res .
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing, but in Gremlin:

```
g.withSideEffect('Neptune#fts.endpoint', '...')
  .V().has(['name', 'company'], 'Neptune#fts term*')
```

This obviously doesn't work. Now I could use wildcard like this:

```
g.withSideEffect('Neptune#fts.endpoint', '...')
  .V().has('*', 'Neptune#fts term*')
```

But now I'm matching all the fields, and it fails because our index has too many. (There's a limit of 1,024 I think.)

**Any idea how to specify a list of fields to search through in a Gremlin query?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Meanwhile I found a workaround, which works but is not very clean:**

You can set your query to use `query_string` format like this:

`.withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.queryType", "query_string")`

It will be less forgiving for syntax, but it means you can search for fields inside the query:

`field1:foo AND field2:bar`

Now with Neptune it's not so simple, because your field names aren't just `field1`, `field2`, but they are formatted like this:

```
predicates: {
  field1: {
    value: "..."
  },
  field2: {
    value: "..."
  }
}
```

That's fine, you just need to modify the query:

`predicates.field1.value:foo AND predicates.field2.value:bar`

And here's how I do **"make sure that some of the fields match term"**:

`predicates.field1.value:<term> OR predicates.field2.value:<term>`

Comment: Hi there, that's the correct way to do it! We are going to update our documentation to make this information available. 

Disclaimer: I'm a the Neptune developer who lead the FTS effort.

Comment: @Vojto Please go ahead and mark this as the answer.